# How do I use Bitnode API?

Tags: api, nodes, bitnodes

I just started running a full node and was wondering how to use these commands to verify my node: https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/api/

Specifically, what command line or IDE do I need to type these commands into? Very new at this, sorry

Answer (score 3):

If you are on MacOS or Linux use

```
curl https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/api/v1/nodes/SERVER-ADDRESS/
```

in Terminal or [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/)

e.g.

```
curl https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/api/v1/nodes/107.3.158.6-8333/
```

will return to you

```
{"detail": "Not found"}
```

because it's not a running node address and port

and

```
curl https://getaddr.bitnodes.io/api/v1/nodes/80.56.212.9-8333/
```

will return to you

```
{"status": "UP", "data": [70002, "/Satoshi:0.10.0/", 1431732528, 1, 356844, "f212009.upc-f.chello.nl", null, "NL", 52.3667, 4.9, "Europe/Amsterdam", "AS6830", "Liberty Global Operations B.V."], "bitcoin_address": "", "url": "", "verified": false}r
```