# Port 8333 closed, fwd on Router OK, firewall port open, full-node not reachable

Tags: port

I have set up my bitcoin/lnd full node and found out that port 8333 is closed.

When checking using https://bitnodes.io it tells me it's down

I've checked the router config and port 8333 is forwarded to the IP of the node.

If I scan or use telnet to connect locally to my node, it seems to be blocked.

Also ufw has been checked and sudo ufw allow 8333/tcp has been added.

As well sudo netstat -tunlp tells me that the port is in listen state.

Now, I'm kind of stuck and looking for help.

Many thanks in advance for a reply and stay healthy.

Comment: I have found bitnodes erroneously reports no inbound access (I use Tor, not sure if this is relevant). Check for inbound connections to your node with `bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo` and check the `inbound` field. If you have `jq` installed run: `bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo | jq '.[] | {addr: .addr, inbound: .inbound}'`. If your node reports inbound connections, the problem may be with bitnodes.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your router opens that port too and redirects that port to you computer.

Then check CGNAT. If the external IP address your router shows isn't the same as you find when you search for "what is my ip", your ISP is giving the same IP to multiple customers. So you won't be able to open a port.

Comment: the port is open on the router and redirects that port to my node. the external address is the same as shown in "what is my ip" but I think that's not the problem, as on my internal network 192.168.1.* my net analyser show that port 8333 is closed.

Comment: I don't understand as the command sudo netstat -lptu, shows me that port 8333 is listening.

tcp        0      0 localhost:8333          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6260/bitcoind

Comment: You can try from another computer in your network to use nmap or [something like this](https://serverfault.com/a/309062) to check if the port on your computer is reachable from your local network too.

Comment: if I disable tor, then port 8333 is open and can be seen by using https://bitnodes.io...

Answer (score 0):

bitnodes.io has been spotty for me, especially when checking availability of .onion addresses, but also regular ipv4 addresses. I've had better luck checking availability with their API, as mentioned in this [StackExchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37446/how-do-i-use-bitnode-api)